# Change the way a node is displayed in drupal

Tags: drupal-6

I am using drupal 6. I created a content type called 'Mobile' using CCK and added content for it. I want to change the way the content is displayed to the user. How do i do this.

Currently [image: Mobile node] looks like this.  I want to play around with the fields in this only for this content type. How do i do it and can i do some work around with the form of the mobile content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions like "teach me how to walk"
You need to learn Drupal theming system. you can get general idea http://drupal.org/node/17565 and by looking at node.tpl.php from your theme - that's for the beginning.

P.S: as far as I see from your other questions, you didn't tried to search in the web for this.